# What's the best way to implement a string buffer in Rust?

Tags: rust

Say I want to do lots of small additions to a string in a row, what's the best way to do this? Is there a data type that's best for this?

Comment: It is not too clear what you are asking for. A buffer can be used in many ways. Maybe a parallel with languages having Interned Strings such as Java or C# since those introduced the `StringBuffer` idea would make it clearer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the String native type, it's designed to be mutable and grow easily.

```
let mut s = String::new();
s.push_str("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n");
s.push_str("User-Agent: foobar\r\n"); // Etc etc
```

Comment: In addition, if you have some idea of the final length of your string, you can initialize `s` as `let mut s = String::with_capacity(some_number)`  to  avoid memory reallocations. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.with_capacity

Answer (score 6):

> Say I want to do lots of small additions to a string in a row [...]

If "additions" are not `&str` you can use the target `String` as a Writer to push string representations of other data types:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut target_string = String::new();
    use std::fmt::Write;
    write!(target_string, "an integer: {}\n", 42).unwrap();
    writeln!(target_string, "a boolean: {}", true).unwrap();

    assert_eq!("an integer: 42\na boolean: true\n", target_string);
}
```

The Write trait is required by the macro `write!`.
Anything which implements `Write` can be written to with the macro `write!`.
To use Write methods, it must first be brought into scope.
The Write trait is brought into scope with `use std::fmt::Write;`.

Documentation:

- `write!(..)`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.write.html
- `writeln!(..)`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.writeln.html

The resource used to write this answer:
[Rust String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714058/rust-string-concatenation/30714382#30714382)