# Rust String concatenation

Tags: string, rust

I started programming with Rust this week and I am having a lot of problems understanding how Strings work.

Right now, I am trying to do a simple program that prints a list of players appending their order(for learning purposes only).

```
let res : String = pl.name.chars().enumerate().fold(String::new(),|res,(i,ch)| -> String {
    res+=format!("{} {}\n",i.to_string(),ch.to_string());
});

println!("{}", res);
```

This is my idea, I know I could just use a for loop but the objective is to understand the different Iterator functions.

So, my problem is that the String concatenation does not work.

```
   Compiling prueba2 v0.1.0 (file:///home/pancho111203/projects/prueba2)
src/main.rs:27:13: 27:16 error: binary assignment operation `+=` cannot be applied to types `collections::string::String` and `collections::string::String` [E0368]
src/main.rs:27             res+=format!("{} {}\n",i.to_string(),ch.to_string());
                           ^~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `prueba2`.
```

I tried using &str but it is not possible to create them from `i` and `ch` values.

Comment: This may not be a true duplicate, but as asked it seems the same. Feel free to update your title and question to better reflect why it isn't a duplicate and we can unmark it as such.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, in Rust `x += y` is not overloadable, so `+=` operator won't work for anything except basic numeric types. However, even if it worked for strings, it would be equivalent to `x = x + y`, like in the following:

```rust
res = res + format!("{} {}\n",i.to_string(),ch.to_string())
```

Even if this were allowed by the type system (it is not because `String + String` "overload" is not defined in Rust), this is still not how [`fold()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) operates. You want this:

```rust
res + &format!("{} {}\n", i, ch)
```

or, as a compilable example,

```rust
fn main(){
    let x = "hello";
    let res : String = x.chars().enumerate().fold(String::new(), |res, (i, ch)| {
        res + &format!("{} {}\n", i, ch)
    });

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

When you perform a fold, you don't reassign the accumulator variable, you need to return the new value for it to be used on the next iteration, and this is exactly what `res + format!(...)` do.

Note that I've removed `to_string()` invocations because they are completely unnecessary - in fact, `x.to_string()` is equivalent to `format!("{}", x)`, so you only perform unnecessary allocations here.

Additionally, I'm taking `format!()` result by reference: `&format!(...)`. This is necessary because `+` "overload" for strings is defined for `String + &str` pair of types, so you need to convert from `String` (the result of `format!()`) to `&str`, and this can be done simply by using `&` here (because of deref coercion).

In fact, the following would be more efficient:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main(){
    let x = "hello";
    let res: String = x.chars().enumerate().fold(String::new(), |mut res, (i, ch)| {
        write!(&mut res, "{} {}\n", i, ch).unwrap();
        res
    });

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

which could be written more idiomatically as

```rust
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main(){
    let x = "hello";

    let mut res = String::new(); 
    for (i, ch) in x.chars().enumerate() {
        write!(&mut res, "{} {}\n", i, ch).unwrap();
    }

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

(try it on [playpen](http://is.gd/yBQUZg))

This way no extra allocations (i.e. new strings from `format!()`) are created. We just fill the string with the new data, very similar, for example, to how `StringBuilder` in Java works. `use std::fmt::Write` here is needed to allow calling `write!()` on `&mut String`.

I would also suggest reading [the chapter on strings](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/strings.html) in the official Rust book (and the book as a whole if you're new to Rust). It explains what `String` and `&str` are, how they are different and how to work with them efficiently.

Comment: "`x += y` is equivalent (in terms of operator overloading) to `x = x + y`" → I thought `+=` wasn't yet overloadable at all.

Comment: I think Veedrac is right

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: Overloading += has been added since this question was originally asked.