# How can I iterate over a backwards range?

Tags: iterator, rust, match

I'm attempting to create `pub fn sing(start: i32, end: i32) -> String` that returns a concatenated string of the results of calling `pub fn verse(num: i32) -> String` repeatedly on each number between `start` and `end`.

I've googled for the answer and it seems that [Rust String concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714058/rust-string-concatenation) answers my question, and if I even write my code in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e0de6de609d9619e0ea5f10114d058cf&version=stable&backtrace=0) it works, but:

my code:

```
pub fn verse(num: i32) -> String {
    match num {
        0 => "No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.\nGo to the store and buy some more, 99 bottles of beer on the wall.\n".to_string(),
        1 => "1 bottle of beer on the wall, 1 bottle of beer.\nTake it down and pass it around, no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n".to_string(),
        2 => "2 bottles of beer on the wall, 2 bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, 1 bottle of beer on the wall.\n".to_string(),
        num => format!("{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0} bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, {1} bottles of beer on the wall.\n",num,(num-1)),
    }
}

pub fn sing(start: i32, end: i32) -> String {
    (start..end).fold(String::new(), |ans, x| ans+&verse(x))
}
```

The problem is that

```
#[test]
fn test_song_8_6() {
    assert_eq!(beer::sing(8, 6), "8 bottles of beer on the wall, 8 bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, 7 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n7 bottles of beer on the wall, 7 bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, 6 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n6 bottles of beer on the wall, 6 bottles of beer.\nTake one down and pass it around, 5 bottles of beer on the wall.\n");
}
```

fails with `beer::sing(8,6)` returning `""`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a reverse ordered for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170091/how-to-make-a-reverse-ordered-for-loop)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with string concatenation. It has to do with the fact that `8..6` is an empty iterator, because a range only iterates forwards. Because `8 >= 6`, the iterator yields `None` on the first call to `next`.

```
fn main() {
    for i in 8..6 {
        println!("{}", i); // never reached
    }
}
```

This can be fixed by swapping `start` and `end` and calling `rev()` to iterate backwards.

```
fn main() {
    for i in (6..8).rev() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

However, there's still another problem. In a range `start..end`, `start` is inclusive but `end` is exclusive. For example, the code above prints `7` and `6`; `8` is not printed. See [How do I include the end value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698191/155423)

Putting it all together, `sing` should look like:

```
pub fn sing(start: i32, end: i32) -> String {
    (end..=start)
        .rev()
        .fold(String::new(), |ans, x| ans + &verse(x))
}
```

Note: Your test still fails because it expects two newlines between each verse, but your code only generates one. I'll leave this up to you to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why does range only iterate forward?

Comment: @CalebJasik: It's not really that it only iterates forward, and more than it models a typical half-open range: `[start end)`. In this sense, `start == end` represents an empty range and `start >= end` a bug. It also makes the Range code simpler (and thus faster). For reverse iteration, you call `rev` explicitly, and you're done.